# Web Audio API getFloatFrequencyData function setting Float32Array argument data to array of -Infinity values

Tags: javascript, audio, filereader, web-audio-api

I'm currently playing around with the Web Audio API in Chrome (60.0.3112.90) to possibly build a sound wave of a given file via FilerReader, AudioContext, createScriptProcessor, and createAnalyser. I have the following code:

```
const visualize = analyser => {
  analyser.fftSize = 256;
  let bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
  let dataArray = new Float32Array(bufferLength);
  analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(dataArray);
}    

loadAudio(file){
  // creating FileReader to convert audio file to an ArrayBuffer
  const fileReader = new FileReader();

  navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
                      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                      navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                      navigator.msGetUserMedia);

  fileReader.addEventListener('loadend', () => {
    const fileArrayBuffer = fileReader.result;

    let audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    let processor = audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(4096, 1, 1);
    let analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();

    analyser.connect(processor);
    let data = new Float32Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

    let soundBuffer;
    let soundSource = audioCtx.createBufferSource();

    // loading audio track into buffer
    audioCtx.decodeAudioData( 
      fileArrayBuffer, 
      buffer => {
        soundBuffer = buffer;
        soundSource.buffer = soundBuffer;

        soundSource.connect(analyser);
        soundSource.connect(audioCtx.destination);

        processor.onaudioprocess = () => {
          // data becomes array of -Infinity values after call below
          analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(data);
        };

        visuaulize(analyser);
      },
      error => 'error with decoding audio data: ' + error.err
    );
  });

  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

Upon loading a file, I get all the way to `analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(data)`. Upon reading the Web audio API docs, it says that the parameter is:

```
The Float32Array that the frequency domain data will be copied to. 
For any sample which is silent, the value is -Infinity.
```

In my case, I have both an mp3 and wav file I'm using to test this and after invoking `analyser.getFloatFrequency(data)`, both files end up giving me `data` which becomes an array of `-Infinity' values.

This may be due to my ignorance with Web Audio's API, but my question is why are both files, which contain loud audio, giving me an array that represents silent samples?

Comment: Are you using Chrome?

Comment: Not totally clear what you're trying to do - but I don't see you actually calling start() on the audiobuffersource, unless it's inside         iHateMyselfForThis.recordAudio(audioCtx, analyser)?

Comment: @RaymondToy yes, I've updated my question with that information

Comment: @cwilso I've revised my code to omit setting context as I'm using this in a stateful react component. As you can see, I'm not invoking start(). I'm trying to get frequencies without having to play the file itself (if possible.

Comment: How else do you think the analyser is going to non-zero samples to analyse if you don't actually start the source that feeds the analyser?

Comment: @RaymondToy I was under the assumption that loading the data itself was sufficient. As well, I'm not necessarily interested in playing the audio immediately unless I absolutely have to.

Comment: Can't really tell what you want to do with the frequency data, but one alternative is to create an OfflineAudioContext with a buffer source and an analyser.  Then use `context.suspend(time).then(() => analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(data)}.then(() => context.resume())` to get the frequency data.  (This only works in chrome; no one else supports suspend in an offline context.)

Comment: @RaymondToy Using the frequency data, I'm trying to build out a visual sound wave in some manner using decoded sound files such as mp3's and wav's. I'll try to see if I can use your suggestion to my advantage.

Comment: @RaymondToy could you please provide your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Web Audio AnalyserNode is only designed to work in realtime.  (It used to be called RealtimeAnalyser.)  Web Audio doesn't have the ability to do analysis on buffers; take a look at another library, like [DSP.js](https://github.com/corbanbrook/dsp.js/).

Comment: There isn't any way to use Web Audio api to build a sound wave representation of an entire song given the song file itself? I've seen multiple projects such as https://wavesurfer-js.org/ which seem to have mastered some sort of technique that allows the rendering of a sound file's sound wave visually.

Comment: No, you totally CAN use Web Audio to build a representation of the entire file - via the OfflineAudioContext - but you can't use an Analyser on it.

Comment: Since the OfflineAudioContext has an AnalyserNode as well this is actually possible.

Comment: @elpoto It's certainly possible to create one, yes.  But the Analyser is a real-time processor - you ask it, in effect, at any time "what's the frequency analysis, or a snipper, of the last chunk of data you got?" - and when you're in an offline context, that's not going to be particularly useful (because it's not "live" - you're probably either at the beginning or the end of the audio data).  The OfflineAudioContext has createAnalyser for symmetry, but it's not particularly useful.

Comment: What the original scenario probably wants is likely some sort of averaged/summed frequency analysis of the entire data set - which isn't what AnalyserNode does.  It works on a much shorter analysis frame - sort of like one vertical slice of the spectrogram that you can create with Wavesurfer.

Comment: You can set the position of the AudioBufferSourceNode and then analyse any part of the buffer. Something like this:
`…
bufferSource.start(0, start, duration);
await offlineContext.startRendering();
const data = new Float32Array(analyserNode.frequencyBinCount);
…`

Comment: But I agree, it's probably not the approach that antihero989 was searching for :)

Comment: @cwilso I just coincidentally saw your contributions to https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api :o Thank you. I realise I have nothing to explain to you :) but maybe this approach is helpful for somebody as it was for me.

Comment: Not at all!  It's a community.

I'm still not sure your suggestion would work predictably.  When you call .startRendering, the offlineContext will start rendering in a different thread as fast as it can; you won't get an analysis from a predictable time slice of the Context.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
soundSource.connect(analyser);
soundSource.connect(audioCtx.destination);
```

try:

```
soundSource.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination);
```

Realising I sould do a source ==> anlalsyser ==>> destination chain solved this problem when I encountered it.